# LNK2019:unresolved external symbol _htmlReadFile referenced in function _main when using libxml

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, libxml2

Im trying to parse HTML document using `libxml2`. I added the extracted `libxml` to my visual studio project by including in VC++ directories under project properties.

When i use `htmlReadFile` by including `libxml/HTMLparser.h`,
I get these errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _htmlReadFile referenced in function _main    
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How do I resolve this, please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think its due to external library. This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx) might help you.

Comment: I ll check the link.. thanks @Pramodab

Comment: You have to also add the library that comes along with the headers. Go to Project properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies and add the .lib file